# How To Format Command Line Argument Key Value Pairs

Tags: command-line, format, standards, command-line-arguments

A typical format for command line arguments is:

```
myApp --myArg=myValue
```

What if I want to pass in a set of key value pairs through the command line? Something like:

```
myApp --myList={arg1=val1;arg2=val2;arg3=val3...}
```

Since [there seems to be no standard for this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725675/is-there-a-standard-format-for-command-line-shell-help-text), can anyone provide examples from well-used utilities that have this sort of command line argument input? I poked around some man pages but didn't find any.

Edit: I'm wondering both how the input should be formatted and what the help text might look like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it largely depends on how you parse the arguments in your program.

Here are some examples that the programs accept multiple key-value pair values.

man php:

```
   --define foo[=bar]
   -d foo[=bar]   Define INI entry foo with value bar
```

man git:

```
   -c <name>=<value>
       Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will
       override values from configuration files. The <name> is expected in
       the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by
       dots).
```

For both, one can pass multiple `-d` or `-c` arguments to the programs which gives you the ability to supply a list of key-value pairs to the programs.

IMO, it's not a big problem having your own style of accepting lists of key-value pairs for your program as long as it *works* and is well-documented. :)

P.S.: I think this question would be more appropriate be placed on [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) rather than on SO. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82988/230550) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68384/230550).

Answer (score 5):

If the app needs so many arguments, I would use a config file instead of passing them in command line:

`myApp --config=file.cnf`

This approach has the following advantages:

- flexibility - you can have a bunch of configs prepared for different invocations, and just use them,
- no problems with quoting - it's always painful if command line arguments have spaces, double quotes, <, >, or other special characters,
- simplicity - you control the config file format, it can be for example INI, JSON, XML etc. It's easy to create it and as easy to parse as parsing command line -- if not easier,
- security - if any argument may be sensitive, it's not visible from tools displaying command line arguments.