# use of <> in man page to indicate optional white space

Tags: linux, unix, manpage

I'm maintaining an old KornShell shell script and its man page.

The shell script's command line options include both **-w***width* (no intervening space) and **-w** *width* (with intervening white space), which have the same effect.  In the man page this is documented in the SYNOPSIS section as [**-w**<>*width*], apparently using <> to mean optional white space.

I haven't been able to find on the Web other UNIX or Linux man pages that use <> for this purpose, so I presume that this doesn't follow a convention that UNIX or Linux users expect, and thus users may be confused by <> in the man page.

Which of the following representations in a man page makes it most clear that white space between the **-w** and *width* is optional:

- [**-w**<>*width*],
- [**-w**[ ]*width*], or
- [**-w***width*|**-w** *width*]?

Is it better to just have *one* of either [**-w***width*] or [**-w** *width*] in the man page, on the basis that they do the same thing so there is little or no value added to the user to document that *both* of these alternatives are available?

Comment: Personally, I recommend choosing one to be preferred. Keep the implementation as it is and in the documentation mention that the other version is obsolete but supported for compatibility.

Comment: Also see Posix's [Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html). GNU does not have the same at [Standards for Command Line Interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html). I wrote to GNU several years ago asking them to document the syntax in the manual. This is probably a duplicate of [Is there a “standard” format for command line/shell help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9725675/608639).

Comment: After posting my question, I've noticed that the HP-UX intro(1) man page uses <> to represent optional white space, as in -arg_letter<>opt_arg.  As no HP-UX man pages for actual commands use <> for this purpose, I think the intent in intro(1) is that it is optional for command synopses to have white space between an argument letter and its option argument, and **not** that there should be a <> in command synopses to indicate optional white space at that point in command lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would just document `-w width` because it's a universal convention that options with arguments can take the argument either in the same command-line argument (`-w80`) or the following command-line argument (`-w 80`).

Any tool/option that does not follow the convention should document it, but your case looks pretty standard.