# Meaning of Python Usage Argument Syntax (ex : Usage example.py [-h] --example {example~~})

Tags: python

Hello I want to know meaning of [],{},-,-

For example, when I execute the python program, program prints "Usage : example.py [-h] example --example {example}

In that, What is mean of [ ], { }, -, -- ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725675/is-there-a-standard-format-for-command-line-shell-help-text?

Comment: For Python specifically: `-a` (arg short name), `--arg_name` (arg long name), `[option1, option2]` additional optional args, `{choice1, choice2}` set list of options / choices (usually strings) to be passed into an arg.  Best resource: [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).